# Do any spanish learners/tutors know where I can find out the spanish version of keyboard keys?

Tags: significado

So after putting in some effort, I found out that "mayús" was shift.

Likewise I was wo wondering if there is a list of keyboard keys along with the spanish version.

Or do I have to go at it one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to compare a picture of the Spanish keyboard layout [from Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teclado_QWERTY) with an English keyboard. In particular:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd>, *Alt*, *Alt Gr*, *Tab* do not change name
- *Retroceso* or *Retr*: Backspace
- *Intro* or *Introducir* or *Entrar*: Enter
- *Control*: Ctrl
- *Mayús*: Shift
- *Bloq Mayús*: Caps Lock
- *Bloq Num*: Num Lock
- *Bloq Despl*: Scroll Lock
- *ImpPnt/PetSis* or *Imp Pant/Pet Sis*: Print Screen/SysRq
- *Pausa/Inter*: Pause/Break
- *Ins* or *Insert*: Insert
- *Supr*: Delete
- *Inicio*: Home
- *Fin*: End
- *RePág*: Page Up
- *AvPág*: Page Down.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I added pictures of the Windows On-Screen Keyboard. If you feel they do not help please remove them or let me know and I will remove them.

Comment: @DGaleano thanks, it is definitely a helpful addition!

Comment: The pictures do not show certain keys that have different meanings.  In particular, I notice that the the key for generating an enye is not labelled as such.  This is the key to the right of the letter L.  looks like this ñ

Comment: @WalterMitty it seems like a UK keyboard layout with translated key names. That probably makes the association of key names in Spanish and English easier for the purpose of this question though...

Comment: @WalterMitty You are right. In Win10 you can type multiple languages on the same keyboard. I have a US keyboard but as Colombian I usually type in Spanish, so the image I added is of the same keyboard layout but set up for either English or Spanish.

Comment: I have a cheat sheet on my desk with the teclado español on it.  Windows has had multi language keyboard support for about 20 years. I heve never had an actual Spanish keyboard.

Comment: I have been typing English and Spanish on the same keybord for about 20 years.  I don't remember when Windows first added support for it. Never owned a Spanish keyboard.